# usb read-only in gui, but works fine from terminal (12.04)

Tags: 12.04, usb, filesystem, read-only

From all that I've read on-line, it appears I have a new twist on the usb-read-only problem.

When I first tried a new usb drive, whenever I tried to drag-drop a file into it, I got the error message saying it was a **read-only device**.

However, I can do anything from the terminal (`mkdir, cp -r` a whole directory to the new drive, etc.) Also, NetBeans happily opens & saves projects from/to the new drive.

As you would expect, since I CAN write to the drive, all of the fixes and probes called for in the old thread about this problem have no effect. The drive is listed as `rw`, for example, and the permissions are what you'd expect, formatting doesn't help, "`mount -o remount`..etc..." does nothing, nor `fsck.vfat -vaV <device>`, nor `dosfsck`, etc.

I also tried gparted, making a new msdos fat32 partition. No change.

I tried formatting as NTFS and installing/running ntfs-config. Even after checking the "enable write support for external device" there is no change.

here is some info that others were asked for relating to this:

`cat /etc/fstab`

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=c4d9491f-6696-46b2-bd42-faf7e77f5c0e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=badd5b20-d8ad-424a-80df-a65f9e8a744a none            swap    sw              0       0
```

`/proc/mounts`

```
rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=4040932k,nr_inodes=1010233,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=810056k,mode=755 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/c4d9491f-6696-46b2-bd42-faf7e77f5c0e / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
none /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime 0 0
gvfs-fuse-daemon /root/.gvfs fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0 0 0
/dev/sdc1 /media/8_8_2015 vfat rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0077,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

executing the following

`sudo mount -o rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,user,exec,umask=003,blksize=4096 /dev/sdc1 /media/toshibaHDD`

produced the message

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error. In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail
```

so here is that result's relevant line:

```
FAT-fs (sdc1): Unrecognized mount option "blksize=4096" or missing value
```

so I tried it without that option...and it's still read-only in the gui.

Have I missed something?

Comment: Please do not write `SOLVED` in the question title. If you have a solution, then write an answer. Or just delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by formatting as ntfs & running `ntfs-config` and then re-booting. Rebooting was not mentioned in the post that suggested this, and I just hadn't tried that yet (although I tried reboot between all the previous steps. Sorry I missed this.)